# How to do integer division (mod) with sparklyr in R?

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparklyr

In R the integer division operator is `%/%`; however, this doesn't work correctly in a spark data frame created by `sparklyr`. For example, `20141025` is transformed to `201410.2` somehow. In the vignette, `sparklyr` doesn't say it supports `%/%`. Then how should integer division be done using `sparklyr`?

Currently I'm doing `floor(a / b)` but I want to know if there is a simple operator for that.

Answer (score 1):

> In R the integer division operator is %/%; however, this doesn't work correctly in a spark data frame created by sparklyr. For example, 20141025 is transformed to 201410.2 somehow.

That's because `sparklyr` doesn't execute plain R code, but uses [SQL translation layer](http://dbplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/translate_sql.html) and `%/%` becomes `/` in SQL:

```
dbplyr::translate_sql(x %/% y)
```

```
<SQL> "x" / "y"
```

> I want to know if there is a simple operator for that.

None that I am aware of. The code you have right now seems like the way to go.